# Unable to run .feature using vscode extension

Tags: karate

I was previously able to run karate files just yesterday but getting "Running tests requires a PLUS subscription. Please sign-in." when I click on the run text about the "Feature:". Also previously "Run >>" was displayed but now ">>" has disappeared.

[Running tests requires a PLUS subscription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZtWK.png)

[">>" disappeard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXLBz.png)

Tried reinstalling VScode and the extension but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karate open-source remains free and under the MIT license. Users/teams/Enterprise can download and use Karate open-source using [Maven, Gradle](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Get-Started:-Maven-and-Gradle), [Standalone JAR, Docker, NPM and JBang](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Get-Started:-Other-Runtime-Options#standalone-jar).

For the IDE plugins (currently VS Code and IntelliJ), effective 30 Oct 2023 - to run tests you need to sign in with at least a PLUS subscription. You can find more information [here](https://www.karatelabs.io/pricing).

Answer (score 1):

You can roll back the extension version to 1.2.0 and the ability to run tests will return.
You can select the "Install another version" option on the "Uninstall" button

I hope this option will be left because... being able to immediately start learning and running your code without additional coding was super convenient.

Comment: He's taken old versions off of the marketplace, of course.

This is a terrible awful decision. It's not even a good plugin, lacks tons of features that would be remotely useful.

I don't know how you release an open source tool and then turn around and start charging people to use it efficiently. Especially when there is already an existing install base of people happily using it to do their jobs, who suddenly can't until they can convince their bosses to shell out $600/yr/seat for all the basic features of any half decent language ide plugin.

Bad taste after bad taste in the mouth

Comment: Honestly if the choice is pay or not, just disable/uninstall the karate plugin entirely and rely on Cucumber plugin. (Which lets you run tests for the low price of free.) The open source tier of the plugin provides very little over the cucumber plugin.